# $\sum r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$ is equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients, telescopic-series

$$\sum r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$$ is equal to?

Here, $r$ varies from $1$ to $n$

I am having difficulty in solving questions involving such telescoping series. While I am easily able to do questions where a term splits into two terms, such question are not coming to me.

I am getting no ideas on how to split such a large term. Maybe a hint or help would get me moving.

Comment: This is related to the concept of [Triangular Numbers generalized to higher dimensions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). Not an answer, just posting for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

By telescopic sum we obtain:
$$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{r=1}^n(r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)-(r-1)r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3))=$$
$$=\frac{1}{5}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)$$

Comment: I think this is the way we are supposed to do it. We call it the 'Vn method'.

Comment: @Siddharth Garg beautiful problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)=24\binom{r+3}{4}$ then exploit the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)
= \sum_{r=1}^n 4! \binom{r+3}{4}
= \sum_{m=4}^{n+3} 4! \binom{m}{4}
$$
Now use Pascal's triangle.

The answer is

> $\displaystyle4! \binom{n+4}{5} = \frac15 n (n + 1) (n + 2) (n + 3) (n + 4)$

Since you mention telescoping, note that:
$$
r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)
= 4! \binom{r+3}{4}
= 4! \left(\binom{r+4}{5} - \binom{r+3}{5}\right)
$$
by Pascal's relation.

Comment: Sir, I don't require the direct answer. I need some help or a hint so that I can do such questions myself when I am giving an exam. A little explanation on how to reach here would definitely help.

Answer (score 2):

To generalize your question concerning 
a very important polynomial (function), note that
$$
r\left( {r + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {r + m - 1} \right) = \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m - 1} {\left( {r + k} \right)}  = r^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = {{\Gamma (r + m)} \over {\Gamma (r)}}
$$
is called [*Rising Factorial (Pochammer symbol)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Among the many properties, it has the fact that its **finite difference** resembles the derivative of $x^m$,
as the sum resembles the integral
$$
\eqalign{
  & \Delta _{\,r} \;r^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = \left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  - r^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = m\;\left( {r + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m - 1\,} }   \cr 
  & \sum {r^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } } \; = \Delta _{\,r} ^{\left( { - 1} \right)} \;r^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = {1 \over {m + 1}}\;\left( {r - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m + 1\,} }  + c \cr} 
$$
where $\sum$ is the [*Antiderivative* or *Indefinite Sum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum)

In your particular case
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum {r\left( {r + 1} \right)\left( {r + 2} \right)\left( {r + 3} \right) = } \sum {r^{\,\overline {\,4\,} } } \; = {1 \over 5}\;\left( {r - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,5\,} }  + c =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 5}\;\left( {r - 1} \right)r\left( {r + 1} \right)\left( {r + 2} \right)\left( {r + 3} \right) + c \cr} 
$$

and for instance:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {r\left( {r + 1} \right)\left( {r + 2} \right)\left( {r + 3} \right)}  = \left. {{1 \over 5}\;\left( {r - 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,5\,} } } \right|_{\;1}^{\;n + 1}  = {1 \over 5}\left( {\;n^{\,\overline {\,5\,} }  - 0^{\,\overline {\,5\,} } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 5}\;n^{\,\overline {\,5\,} }  = {1 \over 5}\;n\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)\left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n + 4} \right) \cr} 
$$
note that the definite sum from $a$ to $b$, corresponds
to the indefinite sum calculated at **$b+1$** minus that calculated at $a$.